# В Global не передается результат выполнения функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, функции, global-variables

Возникли сложности с пониманием работы `global` в *Python*.
Для того, чтобы разобраться, написал простенькие функции - и завис.

В общем, есть два файла:
**func.py**, в нем функция для создания двух списков и заполнения их случайными числами,

**func.py**:

```
def generate_lsts():
    import random
    global list1
    global list2

    list1 = [random.randrange(0, 20) for _ in range(10)]
    list2 = [random.randrange(0, 20) for _ in range(10)]
 
    return list1, list2
```

и

**main.py**

```
from func import generate_lsts as gl

list1:list = []
list2:list = []

gl()

def mxmn(list1, list2):
    return min(list1), max(list2)

print(mxmn(list1, list2))
```

---

Логика планировалась такая: импортируется из файла функция, аннотируются пустые пока списки, вызывается функция из файла, в ней списки объявляются глобальными и возвращаются заполненные рандоно числами. 
Переменные списков переписываются. 
Далее они передаются как параметры в функцию основного файла и она возвращает минимум первого и максимум второго списка.

Но списки как были в Глобал пустыми так и остались после работы функции.

Как оно работает и что не так?

Comment: Функция создает глобальные переменные в своем модуле (т.е. по идее после вызова `gl` вы можете к ним обратиться через `import func; print(func.list1)`). Вместо использования глобальных переменных просто сделайте `list1, list2 = gl()`, тем более что вы эти списки возвращаете из функции.

Comment: Возможно, Вам поможет вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files. Предлагается выделить отдельный модуль под глобалзы, импортировать его во все модули, где они требуются, и обращаться к ним через этот модуль.

Comment: insolor, а, вот оно как работает... Оба варианта сработали, спасибо - но чет неочевидно для меня это было, в JS как то попроще понял и работало))

Comment: Alexey Trukhanov, спасиб, пошел переводить статью)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Павел, я думаю что с пояснениями @insolor , вы уже достаточно ознакомились с глобальными переменными и вот почему, читаем [**Почему глобальные переменные — это зло?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Вот как я вижу вариант решения вашей задачи:

**main.py**

```
from func import generate_lsts as gl

   
class MyClass():    
    list1 = []
    list2 = []

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        
        self.list1, self.list2 = gl()
        print(f'\nlist1 = {self.list1}; \nlist2 = {self.list2}\n') #

    def mxmn(self, list1, list2):
        return min(list1), max(list2)

myClass = MyClass()
_min, _max = myClass.mxmn(myClass.list1, myClass.list2)
print(f'min/list1 = {_min}; max/list2 = {_max}\n')
```

**func.py**

```
import random


def generate_lsts():
    list1 = [random.randrange(0, 20) for _ in range(10)]
    list2 = [random.randrange(0, 20) for _ in range(10)]

    return list1, list2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S. Nick, спасибо. Ну я догадывался как это сделать через классы-методы, но с ними маловато опыта пока. Да и думал что при такой простой задаче не потребуются. Ну если подводить итог: если нужно кидаться переменными из функции в функцию - правильнее создать класс, атрибуты (если надо) получать из какой-то функции или напрямую, а вот функции, куда передавать и где использовать эти атрибуты, писать как методы класса?

Comment: @Павел пожалуйста. Лиха беда начало. Пробуйте, дерзайте и все получится. Будут проблемы - задавайте новый вопрос, прикладываете ваш код с попытками решения, и описанием того, что вы хотите сделать.